# correct way to access hostname in android app

Tags: android, dns, hostname

I have another simple issue that i'm unsure of the correct fix for. I have a local SQL server, and a local ASP.net API to communicate with the SQL server and deliver JSON strings. This bit works fine.

When I try to access this server in an android app though I get an error because the server name does not match the certificate (I'm trying to access it by IP address).

What is the correct way around this?

For testing I'm using a VPN app that reroutes the traffic.

Is there a way to specify a host name in code? Or is the only way to have a DNS server aware of the name? The certificate is assigned to the machine name of the computer, is there any other way of doing this?

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

I still can't find an easy way to do this. I've given up.

You either need a rooted device and edit the hosts file which is pretty difficult on Android.

Or, and the option I went for. Setting up a custom DNS server to resolve the internal addresses, not ideal but it works.